# Is there any way to validate AZURE permission levels through API

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-rest-api

Normally in AWS and GCP, there are API calls to validate their assigned user permission levels.
Eg:- User has Cloud SQL Client role in GCP and if the API call is executed with permission cloudsql.instances.get, it will retrun whether the permission is granted or not.

So likewise is there any way to validate AZURE permission levles?

Currently it is only possible to list available permission
As a example it will return  "*/read" and through this API it is given set of permissions

But my requirement is to validate the access level by passing the exact permission levles `"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read"`

or to list all the exact set of permission sets 
eg:-

```
"Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/read",
"Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/read",
"Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/read",
"Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read",
```